# Trying to show convergence (in probability) of integrals using Taylor expansion

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, taylor-expansion, parameter-estimation

I've been working for a long time now on how to prove a proposition given in a
paper about the asymptotic normality of POT-quantile estimators. Hope somebody
can help me out.

**Proposition**

(i) Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be
iid RV and $X_{1:n}\le\ldots \le X_{n:n}$ the corresponding order statistics.

(ii) Let $k=k_n$ and $p=p_n$ be sequences in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ with
$k=k_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \infty$, $\frac{k}{n}=\frac{k_n}{n}\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$ and
$\frac{k}{np}=\frac{k_n}{np_n}
\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \infty$ so that $\frac{\log\left( \frac{k}{np}
\right) }{\sqrt{k}} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0.$

(iii) Let
$\widehat{\gamma_k}=\widehat{\gamma_{k_n}}(X_{n-k+1:n},\ldots,X_{n:n})$ be an estimator for some $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$. ($\widehat{\gamma_k}$ is an estimator depending on the $k$ upper order statistics.) Assume that
$G_k:=\sqrt{k}(\widehat{\gamma_k}-\gamma)\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{d} G \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Then $$ (\ast) \quad \frac{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\widehat{\gamma_k}-1} \log
s\, ds}{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\gamma-1} \log s\, ds}
\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{P} 1. $$

---

$\underline{\text{Hint given in the paper}}$: "The proof is direct. It follows from Taylor expansions
and the fact that $\widehat{\gamma_k}=\gamma+ \frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}$."

My ideas so far:

Define $f(s)=s^{\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}}$

Taylor expansion in $1$:

$f(s)=1+f'(\xi_s)(s-1)=1+\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}
\xi_s^{\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}-1}(s-1)$ for some $\xi_s \in (1,s).$
 Then
$$(\ast) = \frac{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\gamma-1} s^{\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}} \log
s\, ds}{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\gamma-1} \log s\, ds}
= \frac{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\gamma-1} (1+\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}
\xi_s^{\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}-1}(s-1)) \log
s\, ds}{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\gamma-1} \log s\, ds}$$

$$=1+ \frac{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}} s^{\gamma-1} \frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}
\xi_s^{\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}-1}(s-1) \log
s\, ds}{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\gamma-1} \log s\, ds}=:1+(\ast \ast)$$
Need to show: $(\ast \ast) \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{P} 0.$
It is
$$(\ast \ast)\le G_k \frac{log\left( \frac{k}{np}
\right) }{\sqrt{k}} \frac{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\gamma-1}
\xi_s^{\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}-1}(s-1) \, ds}{\int_1^{\frac{k}{np}}s^{\gamma-1} \log s\, ds}$$
and from the Slutsky theorem I know that $G_k \frac{\log\left( \frac{k}{np}
\right) }{\sqrt{k}}\xrightarrow[n \to \infty ]{d}0. $
I haven't been able to work out what happens to the rest term, though.

I know
that $\frac{G_k}{\sqrt{k}}=\widehat{\gamma_k}-\gamma \xrightarrow[n\to
\infty]{p} 0$ but not how fast in comparison to the interval $(1,s)$ that
$\xi_k$ lies in (the upper limit of interval tends to $\infty$ with $n$ because $\frac{k}{np}$ does). Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this? The hint says "Taylor expansion**s**", so maybe I need one more to make it work?

Thanks in advance!